# Using powi when iterating over the elements of a Vec

Tags: rust

This code works correctly and gives the result as `14`:

```
fn main() {
    let v: i32 = vec![1, 2, 3].iter().map(|x| x * x).sum();
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b73b73b42dcbfc90d1da8f4a908e7bdf&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

I'm trying to replace the `x * x` by `powi(2)` so I tried both options below, but neither of them work:

```
let v1: i32 = vec![1, 2, 3].iter().map(|x| x.powi(2)).sum();
```

```
let v2: i32 = vec![1, 2, 3].iter().map(|&x| &x.powi(2)).sum();
```

I've also [posted this to the Rust user's forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/using-powi-with-vecc-elements/21023?u=hasanoryx).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3866c1df93bfc1fe0c63bb881ee3a388&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: @Stargateur what if my `vec!` is of integers?

Comment: If they are integers, why are you using `powi`? That is for floating-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard library, `powi` is only implemented for the two built-in floating point types:

- [`f32::powi`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.powi)
- [`f64::powi`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.powi)

If you wish to apply a power to an integer type, you want to use the inherent method `pow` (e.g. [`i32::pow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.pow)):

```
let v: i32 = vec![1i32, 2, 3].iter().map(|x| x.pow(2)).sum();
```